# Can I insert my own website building in HTML, CSS, JS in WIX using the same hosting and domain?

Tags: html, hosting, velo

I have already a website in WIX and I paid for my domain and hosting but now I would like to upload my own website using the same domain and hosting, it is possible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about a programming problem. Questions about the services offered by a hosting service are best directed at their customer support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, **it is not possible to import** a website built in HTML, CSS, JS outside of Wix to Wix.
Here you have an article published by Wix answering to your question :
[Request: Importing a Site Created Outside of Wix](https://support.wix.com/en/article/request-importing-a-site-created-outside-of-wix)